# can't get another user profile image - google play game service

Tags: android, uri, google-play-games, loadimage

---

i'm not good english. sorry..

my question about "goole play game service"  is this.

---

i used "google play game service".
i applied multiplay.
when i get connected user profile photo, arise error.
This success that   bring my profile photo.
another user profile photo not bring.
why?

```
for (Participant p : mParticipants) {

        Log.d(TAG, "startGetGoogleImage.6");

        //Log.d(TAG, "photo => "    + p.getIconImageUri().toString());
        if (!(p.getParticipantId().equals(mMyId))) {

            //Log.d(TAG, "YOU photo."   + p.getIconImageUri().toString());
            imageManager.loadImage(new OnImageLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageLoaded(Uri uri, Drawable drawable) {
                    try {
                        Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
                        final byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                        // ... some code
                        mCocos2dxGLSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // begin((int) arry[1]);
                                // begin();
                                sendImageByte(byteArray);
                            }
                        });
                        Log.d(TAG, "LoadImageFromGoogle Image added #"
                                + byteArray.length);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG,
                                "LoadImageFromGoogle after loading Exception = "
                                        + e.toString());
                    }
                }

            }, p.getIconImageUri(), android.R.drawable.btn_star);
        }
        // Log.d(TAG, "Participant Name."+p.getDisplayName().toString());

    }
```

error message..

```
android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

Comment: Check this out sih, https://code.google.com/p/dynamicg-android-apps2/source/browse/trunk/HomeButtonLauncher/src/com/dynamicg/homebuttonlauncher/tools/IconProvider.java?spec=svn1011&r=1011

Comment: nOiAd - i checked link. but i can't get another user profile photo.